# How to make variable inside a '' requered command

Tags: python

So I am basicaly trying to write an program which would type number after number in order. pyautogui.press needs text to be in '' but I want it to use a variable "a" which I will increase by 1 every time. Is it possible making this work? Here is the code:

```
import pyautogui
import time
a=1
time.sleep(5)
for i in range (5):
        pyautogui.typewrite()
        pyautogui.press('enter')
        a=a+1
        time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: `pyautogui.press(str(a))`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to convert anything in Python to string (text, usually represented inside quotation marks e.g. 'enter' or "enter"), use the str function to convert:

```
something = 1
something_as_string = str(something)
```

You will find something_as_string has the value '1'.

In your case, you actually don't need `a` at all since you have `i` which takes all values from 0 to 4 inclusive (that's what range(`x`) function does, it iterates over numbers `0` to `x-1` in sequence). So you could just use:

```
import pyautogui
import time
time.sleep(5)
for i in range(5):
        pyautogui.typewrite()
        pyautogui.press(str(i+1))
        time.sleep(2)
```